# Symfony2 Request Password Request Not Generating Token

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working on a Symfony2 application and everyone now and then when a user requests a password the link will not have the token appended to it thus making the link invalid.

We are using the basic settings for password reset which can be viewed here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/emails.html

I think it happens because $token->generateToken() returns nothing but I'm not 100% sure that thats the case.

I've tried and tried but I can't seem to figure out why this happens. Any input would be great.

Thanks!

config:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: FYP\UserBundle\Entity\User
    group:
        group_class: FYP\UserBundle\Entity\Group
    registration:
        form:
            type: fyp_user_registration
            validation_groups: [Registration]
            handler: fyp_user.form.handler.registration
    profile:
        form:
            type: fyp_user_profile
    from_email:
        address:        sender email
        sender_name:    sender name
```

Firewalls:

```
firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            oauth:
                failure_path: /login
                login_path:  /login
                check_path: /connect_check
                provider: fos_userbundle
                remember_me:  true
                always_use_default_target_path: false
                default_target_path: /login
                success_handler: authentication_handler
                failure_handler: authentication_handler
                resource_owners:
                    facebook: "/external-login/check-facebook"
                    paypal: "/external-login/check-paypal"
                    amazon: "/external-login/check-amazon"
                oauth_user_provider:
                    service: app.provider.oauth
                remember_me:
                    key:      %secret%  # pararmeter
                    lifetime: 31536000  # 365 days in seconds
                    path:     /
                    domain:   ~
                    always_remember_me: true
            form_login:
                login_path:  /login
                check_path:  /login_check
                success_handler: authentication_handler
                failure_handler: authentication_handler
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                remember_me:  true
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
            switch_user: { role: ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH, parameter: _new_user }
            remember_me:
                key:      %secret%  # pararmeter
                lifetime: 31536000  # 365 days in seconds
                path:     /
                domain:   ~
                always_remember_me: true
```

Comment: This question misses lots of info, what steps did you take, what code / config do you have in place? What cookbook articles did you follow? When does it exactly happen? Please elaborate on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For some reason some conformation token values in the database where set to '' instead of null. The fix was just to update those rows.

Thanks.